# Call element in 2 dimensional array in laravel

Tags: laravel

## items: array:2 [▼

```
0 => Tour {#229 ▼
  #table: "tour"
  #...
  #attributes: array:12 [▼
    "id" => 6
    "name" => "Nha Trang Tour"
    "price" => 3500000.0
    "price_promotion" => 0.0
    "id_package" => 4
    "id_location" => 8
    "start_time" => "2018-01-27"
    "end_time" => "2018-01-28"
    "star" => 4.0
    "description" => "Funny"
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => "2017-12-29 00:00:00"
  ]
  #...
}
1 => Tour {#230 ▶}
```

I need to call 2 id_location in 2 arrays 0 and 1 in "#items", i use

```
($sale['items']->id_location);
```

and

```
($sale->id_location);
```

but can not take it, and i use

```
($sale[0]->id_location);
```

then succeed, but only get one

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-pluck) method if it's a collection or [`array_pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-pluck) if it's an array:

```
$sale->pluck('id_location');
array_pluck($sales, 'id_location');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you very much :D, I took the table successfully, 
But when I use the view, the case is: view in ["Weekend Package"] instead of Weekend Package 
[image]